# Apple Automator: where does it store a new filename?

Tags: finder, applescript, automator

I have a line of code (that I can run successfully in Terminal) I'd like to incorporate into an Automator workflow but I can't work out how to reference the filename. I've set up my workflow as a Folder Action and applied it to the correct folder so dragging a new file to that folder triggers the workflow (this part is working correctly).

My line of code is

`sudo xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine [PATHNAME_TO_FILE]`

It sets the preferences on the file to obviate Apple's quarantine process run by the Logic program, allowing a third-party file to pass muster.

What does Automator want me to use as [PATHNAME_TO_FILE]? I've tried "$@", "$#", "$0", "$1", "$2", etc, etc. but had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've set up an **Automator**  *workflow* as a **Folder Action** and have added a **Run Shell Script** *action*, you'd set **Shell: [/bin/bash]** and **Pass input: [as arguments]** and use the following *example* **shell script** *code*:

```bash
for f in "$@"
do
    xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine "$f"
done
```

**Note:** You should not need to use `sudo` as you've shown in your OP.

---

**Update to address comment:**

If the target of the *watched folder* is `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components`, as in the *root* of the **Macintosh HD**, then you'll need to take a different approach.

Set up an **Automator**  *workflow* as a **Folder Action** adding a **Run AppleScript** *action*, replacing the *default code* with the *example* **AppleScript** *code* shown below.

Testing under **macOS Catalina** 10.15.6 the **Automator** *workflow* **Folder Action**, described immediately above, worked for me when adding *file(s)/folder(s)* to `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components`, as in the *root* of the **Macintosh HD**.

- **Note:** Upon manually placing *file(s)/folder(s)* into the target *watched folder* and authenticating that action, I was then prompted to re-enter my credentials so the `do shell script` *command* would run as if using `sudo` on the *command line* in **Terminal** on the `xattr` *command*
  .

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
on run {input}
    set itemList to {}
    repeat with aItem in input
        set end of itemList to quoted form of (POSIX path of aItem) & space
    end repeat
    set shellCMD to "xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine " & itemList as string
    do shell script shellCMD with administrator privileges
end run
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had come to the same conclusion regarding the "sudo" command. Unfortunately this code is still not having the desired effect. The workflow is successfully triggering and showing a "working" wheel in the upper menu bar: when I click on this I see progress and then a "failed" message.

Comment: @LigetiFan, Please provide the particulars of your **Folder Action** in an edited update to your question. What _folder_ is being _watched_ and where that _folder_ located? How are the files been placed in the _watched folder_? Also add a screenshot of the **Folder Action** as shown in **Automator**.  what version of **macOS** are you running?   Without this additional information there is no way for us to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Folder being watched is located at /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components. Files would usually be placed by either dragging into the folder or unzipping a .zip file to that location (both methods are successfully triggering the workflow). Running macOS Catalina 10.15.7. I'm not sure how to attach a screenshot but so far my workflow is just your shell script code attached to that folder!

Comment: @LigetiFan, Are the files going into `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components`, as in the _root_ of the **Macintosh HD**, or are they going into `~/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components` as in one's **Home** _folder?_ If the former, then that's going to be an issue. Which is it, and are individual _files_, _folders_ or both being adde to _watched folder_?

Comment: @LigetiFan, Please see the **Update to address comment:** section of my updated answer.

Comment: I'm sorry not to have replied but you've anticipated me anyway: it is indeed files going into the Macintosh HD. And your code does exactly what I've been trying to do. I'm eternally grateful.